# How to call onclientclick after onclick

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, onclick, onclientclick

I've got this button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnReviewDocs" CssClass="btnReviewDocs" data-theme="b"
                Text="Review Documents" OnClick="btnReviewDocs_Click" OnClientClick="clickHyperlink();"/>
```

And in 'OnClick' event I'm assembling an URL that I need to set to asp:Hyperlink and at the end of the 'OnClick' I'm setting this URL to the 'NavigateURL' propery of the 'asp:Hyperlink'. Once the 'asp:Hyperlink' has the correct URL I need to call the 'clickHyperlink()' function.

```
function clickHyperlink() {
    var href = $('#hlnkID').attr('href');
    if (typeof href !== "undefined") {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        window.location.href = href;
    }
}
```

But the 'OnClientClick' event is executed always before the 'OnClick'. Any suggestions for a workaround?

I'm doing all this stuff, because I've got problems with JQuery Mobile and 'Response.Redirect(url);' is changing the page, but not the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you don't really need to involve the `Hyperlink` control in the JS part.
Modify your JS function and remove the `OnClientClick` attribute from the `btnReviewDocs` button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickHyperlink(href) {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        window.location.href = href;
    }
</script>
```

On the server, in the `btnReviewDocs_Click` method:

```
protected void btnReviewDocs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: set the url, maybe append some params to the 
    // hlnkID.NavigateUrl value
    var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), 
        "clickHyperlink",
        "clickHyperlink('" + url + "');",
        true);
}
```

Comment: What if the function is defined in a js file say MyPage.js?

Comment: It should still work, if you add a script reference to the JS file.

Comment: I've added a breakpoint on the line with 'ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript...' and inside the 'clickHyperlink' (I'm using google chrome) but the breakpoint inside the clickHyperlink function doesn't fire and also I'm not redirected to the new URL.

Comment: Please make sure that you use the latest code sample from my answer, as I've initially inserted a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `RegisterStartupScript` in the `ClientScript` object to run the code after postback--->

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //some code    
        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clintClick", "clickHyperlink", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    protected void btnReviewDocs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //something doing here

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "<script type='text/javascript'>clickHyperlink()</script>");//call javascript function
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mentioned by @Alex Filipovici.

But first you should ask yourself do you really need to go back to the client side to do a redirect ?

Why not call :

```
Response.Redirect("MyURL");
```

Comment: I've mentioned why - I'm experiencing problems with JQuery Mobile and was looking for a workaround, which led me to the current situation.